# Single module turns into a package on PyPi when using Python 3 setuptools

Tags: python, pypi

I'm trying to change a python module that I have earlier published on PyPi. I have single python file called gaiaclient.py which has class called Client.

If I install the old version with `pip install gaiaclient==0.0.9` everything works as it should. I can call it like this:

```
>>> import gaiaclient
>>> myclient = gaiaclient.Client("http://localhost:1234")
```

`pip show -f gaiaclient` shows that it installed these files:

```
Files:
  __pycache__/gaiaclient.cpython-36.pyc
  gaiaclient-0.0.9.dist-info/INSTALLER
  gaiaclient-0.0.9.dist-info/METADATA
  gaiaclient-0.0.9.dist-info/RECORD
  gaiaclient-0.0.9.dist-info/WHEEL
  gaiaclient-0.0.9.dist-info/top_level.txt
  gaiaclient.py
```

As you see there is just gaiaclient.py module on top level and no  `__init__.py` file.

Now I would like to publish new version of the gaiaclient but I just can't get it working same way it was!  After my trials I'm on version 0.0.15 now.
My setup.py looks like this:

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="gaiaclient",
    version="0.0.15",
    license='MIT License',
    author="JOT Automation Ltd.",
    author_email="rami.rahikkala@jotautomation.com",
    description="Client for JOT Automation gaia machines",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/jotautomation/gaiapythonclient",
    py_modules=['gaiaclient'],
    install_requires=['requests'],
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
)
```

(The whole project can be found from [github](https://github.com/jotautomation/gaiapythonclient))

I have tried to install the package I generate with command `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` locally with command `pip install dist/gaiaclient-0.0.15.tar.gz` and then it still works as with the version 0.0.9. When the same package is published on PyPi (`twine upload dist/*`) things changes.

When I install it from pypi `pip install gaiaclient==0.0.15` it installs also gaiaclient/**init**.py and gaiaclient/gaiaclient.py in addition to toplevel gaiaclient.py! I.e. it is a package now. How can I make it stop to include the extra files? Because now I cannot anymore just `import gaiaclient` but I have to do it like this `from gaiaclient import gaiaclient` which I would not like to do.

File listing with 0.0.15 version installed from PyPi:

```
Files:
  __pycache__/gaiaclient.cpython-36.pyc
  gaiaclient-0.0.15.dist-info/INSTALLER
  gaiaclient-0.0.15.dist-info/LICENSE
  gaiaclient-0.0.15.dist-info/METADATA
  gaiaclient-0.0.15.dist-info/RECORD
  gaiaclient-0.0.15.dist-info/WHEEL
  gaiaclient-0.0.15.dist-info/top_level.txt
  gaiaclient.py
  gaiaclient/__init__.py
  gaiaclient/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc
  gaiaclient/__pycache__/gaiaclient.cpython-36.pyc
  gaiaclient/gaiaclient.py
```

### Edit 1:

I tried the approach Score_Under suggested i.e. added `__init__.py` with `from gaiaclient.gaiaclient import Client`. This doesn't change anything. This approach probably would need also change to setup.py because now the `gaiaclient/__init__.py` is different than what I specified.

Okay, one more try. This time I added `packages=['.'],` to setup.py. Now it actually works. But! Look at the file listing now:

```
Files:
  __init__.py
  __pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc
  __pycache__/example.cpython-36.pyc
  __pycache__/example_gcode.cpython-36.pyc
  __pycache__/gaiaclient.cpython-36.pyc
  example.py
  example_gcode.py
  gaiaclient-0.0.17.dist-info/INSTALLER
  gaiaclient-0.0.17.dist-info/METADATA
  gaiaclient-0.0.17.dist-info/RECORD
  gaiaclient-0.0.17.dist-info/WHEEL
  gaiaclient-0.0.17.dist-info/top_level.txt
  gaiaclient.py
```

`__init__.py` is now on the root level i.e. on the site-packages directory. This is not good. And still, some how it was working before without `__init__.py`.

### Edit 2:

Now I found out how I got it working before. I did use python 2 to run `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`.

Question still remains that how on earth I can publish single module using python 3 setuptools? Is the behaviour I see because of implicit namespace introduced in python 3.3?

Comment: I have never distributed a single-file package, but you might want to convert to the usual directory structure and then import things in your `__init__.py`. If you have `from gaiaclient.gaiaclient import Client` in your `__init__.py`, then Client becomes available in the `gaiaclient` package itself.

Comment: Actually I tried this earlier and some how the ```__init__.py``` didn't go to the package file. I will try this and update my question.